# CSS positioning of the elements

Tags: html, css

How do I reduce the space between the elements. It should not break when the screen size is reduced, ie should be responsive.

Following is the stack snippet.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="vote-up"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc fa-3x"></i></a>
<h3 class="total_votes"> 1 </h3>
<a class="vote-down"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc fa-3x"></i></a>
```

I however tried playing with `position, top, and bottom` css attributes, but couldnt get the desired results. Also, I tried removing the default margin and padding on the h3 element via CSS, but that has a very minimal effect. How can I reduce the empty space. Also, I dont want to remove `fa-3x` class. I want that `1` and `down-arrow` to move upwards. Kindly help.

Comment: hey you can change in "fa fa-sort-desc fa-3x" this class. then it it affected. changes in verticle-align and line-height property and check it.

Comment: The up pointing arrow uses only the upper half of the character cell. That is, the white space is actually inside the character.

Comment: @KiranKhatri-  Thanks for the input. reducing line-height moves the down-arrow upwards. Now how can I move `1` up as well?

Comment: @MrLister- So any idea how can I merge the spaces in between?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```css
h3{
  margin-top:-3%;
  margin-bottom:-3%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="vote-up"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc fa-3x"></i></a>
<h3 class="total_votes"> 1 </h3>
<a class="vote-down"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc fa-3x"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide extra space by giving fixed height

```css
.vote-up, .vote-down{
 display: inline-block;
 height: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.vote-down .fa-sort-desc{
 position: relative;
 top: -25px;
}
h3.total_votes{
 margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="vote-up"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc fa-3x"></i></a>
<h3 class="total_votes"> 1 </h3>
<a class="vote-down"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc fa-3x"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` of the `total_votes` element.

```css
.vote {
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.total_votes {
  margin: -1em 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="vote">
  <a class="vote-up"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc fa-3x"></i></a>
  <h3 class="total_votes">1</h3>
  <a class="vote-down"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc fa-3x"></i></a>
</div>
```